# Call aspx.cs file function from jquery

Tags: c#, jquery, .net, asp.net-mvc, webforms

I have button in aspx file as below :

```
<asp:Button ID="btnSave" Style="display: none;" runat="server" OnClick="btnSave_Click" />
```

Now in aspx.cs file I have below function.

```
protected void btnSave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
//some code
    }
```

Now I want to call this btnSave_Click function from jquery, so I tried below but it is not calling this function..

```
function btnclick() {
$('#btnSave').click();
            }
```

Any idea, why function is not calling from this jquery code to cs file ?

Thanks

Comment: What is the client-side HTML for that button?  Does it have the same `id` value as the server-side control?

Comment: Above that button I have few checkboxes, user can select any of that checkboxes and based on that values I am updating further code..

Comment: Ok... but how are those checkboxes relevant to the question?  What "updating further code" are you doing, and how does that affect the code shown?  Also... What is the client-side HTML for that button? Does it have the same `id` value as the server-side control?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can "click" a button, and I often do this is place of coding out a webmethod.

So, add this to your button:

```
<asp:Button ID="btnSave" 
          Style="display: none;" runat="server" 
          OnClick="btnSave_Click"
          ClientIdMode="static"
 />
```

So, above then will allow your JavaScript code of this:

```
function btnclick() {
    $('#btnSave').click();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to decorate a method in you aspx.cs file with WebMethod attribute like below:

```
[WebMethod()]
public static string GetData(string name)
{
    //method body
}
```

Then you can make an AJAX call for it from Javascript.

I think the below link will explain:
https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/dacca2/static-webmethod-in-code-behind-webform/

OR if you just want to click the button from JS, you can use:

```
$('#<%=btnSave.ClientID%>').click();
```

instead of:

```
$('#btnSave').click();
```